# How to get width from all elements in jQuery collection

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't `$(".elm").width()` return the width of all elements combined? Is this by design, or some sort of bug?

Or is there some other way to get the width of all elements combined other than this:

```
var width = 0;
$(".elm").each(function() {
    width += $(this).width();
});
```

Comment: post your html code if you can

Comment: $(".elm").width() will return the first matched element, not all elements.

Comment: from documentation about `width()` method: "Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: I'd say it's by design, given the [function description in the API](http://api.jquery.com/width/): *Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width doesn't return the combined width by design, because this may not be the expected value you're looking for.

There is no easy way of telling if the elements are positioned horizontally one after each other. They can be anywhere on the page or even within each other, because a jQuery object may be a combined or edited list of elements.

What does a combined width of elements mean that are cluttered all over your page?

You already found the easiest way of getting the combined width :)

Comment: I was actually using it with `.prevAll()`, so in that context it made sense to just get the width of all the previous elements to position the current one. For some reason I managed to skip the description in the jQuery API and just read the content, which is why I didn't see that it is by design. Nevermind, then.